# How can I make a bootable USB drive to replace Windows?

Tags: installation, usb

I am receiving this error message when I try to move Ubuntu to my USB drive to boot off of it to replace Windows:

```
Could not move syslinux files in '/media/sasha/DA74-E37F':[Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

Maybe `/media/disk` is not an Ubuntu image?

Is this is an issue with my computer or a missing function within Ubuntu?

Comment: Let me get this straight: you want a USB with Ubuntu on it, so when you boot into it - it's like a normal computer and acts like a hard-drive? Or did you want to move files onto the USB? Did you want to make a Live USB? You may also want to add the information in answer to these questions into the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a bootable Ubuntu USB stick from within Windows please follow the instructions :
[How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Also you can use Unetbootin instead of Universal USB installer.

See the general page of Unetbootin here : [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)